# How to generate vector like list comprehension

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, list-comprehension

In C++11,

```
vector<string> blockPathList;
for(int i = 0; i < blockNum; i++)
{
    blockPathList.push_back(desPath + "part" + to_string(i));
}
```

Is it possible to re-write the code above like list comprehension, or shorter and more concise?

Comment: What's `blockNum` and `desPath`?

Comment: It looks like you're turning 1 type of list (vector) into another. This seems like a job for a `map` function, which I'm fairly sure C++ has.

Comment: @VincentSavard `blockNum` is just an int, and `desPath` is a `string`

Comment: @ChenZhongPu: My point is those information should be in your question so it can be answered appropriately. Read more about [mcve].

Comment: Does C++ support list comprehensions? You're probably looking for Haskell or Python

Comment: Is `std::generate` something you'd be interested in (though in this case you'd need to pre-size the vector)?

Comment: C++ doesn't have anything as nice as C#'s `yield return`/`yield break` or Python's `yield` (or even nicer shorthand).  Boost has something ( http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/iterator/doc/function_input_iterator.html ) which you could use or imitate.

Answer (score 13):

Do you want to use third-party libraries? Eric Niebler's [range-v3](https://ericniebler.github.io/range-v3/) allows for:

```
std::vector<string> blockPathList =
        view::ints(0, blockNum)
        | view::transform([&desPath](int i) {
            return desPath + "part" + std::to_string(i);
        });
```

That's about as functional list-comprehension-y as you're going to get in C++.

Comment: @Rotem OP was asking for a list comprehension.

Comment: That's one incomprehensible list comprehension, but she *did* ask for it.

Comment: Note that the `range-v3` library is going to be part of the standard as of C++20.

Answer (score 6):

Not pretty either, but should also get the job done:

```
int cur = 0;
std::vector<std::string> blockPathList(blockNum);
std::generate(blockPathList.begin(), blockPathList.end(),
        [&](){ return destPath + "part" + std::to_string(cur++); });
```

Unfortunately this

- Requires the vector to be pre-sized
- Requires an external iteration variable (since the `std::generate` `Generator` does not take any arguments.

You can also use `std::for_each`:

```
std::vector<int> nums(blockNum);
std::iota(nums.begin(), nums.end(), 0);
std::for_each(nums.begin(), nums.end(), [&](int c) {
        blockPathList.push_back(destPath + "part" + std::to_string(c));
        });
```

but again this is uglified because `std::iota` doesn't generate ranges. It populates an existing range with an iterator, rather than acting as a numeric iterator in-itself (of course you can solve that by implementing or using something which generates those iterators)

Comment: You don't have to pre-size the vector if you use `generate_n` (C++11) and `back_inserter`.

Answer (score 5):

Another example (c++14):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

template<typename CONTAINER, typename LAMBDA>
auto comprehension(CONTAINER&& container, LAMBDA&& lambda){
      std::vector<decltype(lambda(*container.begin()))> w;
      std::transform(container.begin(),container.end(),std::back_inserter(w), lambda);
      return w;
}
int main(){
    auto&& ints = {1,2,3,4,5};
    auto&& squares = comprehension(ints,[](auto i){ return i*i; });

    for( auto s : squares){ std::cout << s << ' '; }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
1 4 9 16 25
```

Comment: Could adding `w.reserve(container.size());` improve performance?

Comment: yes, it should improve it